# How to send a lot of request, but to process the result from the first, before sending the second one using angular and Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have 500 users from the first request this.userService.getAll(), and for every of the users I request 2 other properties (lists) that they have. Unfortunately it sends all 1000 requests at once, and it doesn't first process the first request, than the second request and so on. I want the result for the first user and his property P1 to be displayed right away on the page. I can see that all request are process after they are sent, because the logs from "console.log('request one result');" are printed after the logs for the request. I use rxjs library and httpClient from angular. The app is with angular 7.

```
this.userService.getAll().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.users = data.users;
      if (data && data.users){
        data.users.forEach(user => {

            this.userService.getP1(user.id).subscribe(
            (data: any) => { 
                console.log('request one result');
                if(data) user.p1 = data.p1; });

            this.userService.getP2(user.id).subscribe(
            (data: any) => { 
                console.log('request two result');
                if(data) user.p2 = data.p2; });
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [concat()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html) to subscribe to observables in sequence. Concat will emit the values from each observable in a row. One after another when an observable completes.

```
this.userService.getAll().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.users = data.users;

      const observables = data.users.map(user => {
          return combineLatest(
              this.userService.getP1(user.id),
              this.userService.getP2(user.id)
          );
      });

      concat(...observables).subscribe(([dataP1, dataP2]) => {
         console.log({dataP1,dataP2});
         if(dataP1) user.p1 = dataP1.p1;
         if(dataP2) user.p2 = dataP2.p2;
      });
    });
```